# Someone is moving my pointer & pulling it elsewhere

Tags: microsoft-excel

Someone is trying to pull my pointer elsewhere from where I'm moving it. It feels like a fight with an imaginary person to stop them from moving it. What's going on?   Doris

Comment: Check and remove all usb devices to your computer (except your own hard wired mouse). Someone probably has the mouse and is moving it around behind your back.

Comment: turn the mouse over and look for a hair on the sensor.  Depending on the mouse (and hair colors in your work area) it could be nearly invisible - a flashlight and magnifying glass can be helpful.

Comment: Tell them to stop. If it doesn't work, call the police or a witch doctor.

Answer (score 0):

I my experience, a fine hair trapped under the sensor will cause this behavior, especially if it is a laser-based mouse. It can be very small, you may need a tweezers or something similar to catch it and get it out.